# Computing a series in closed form

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\alpha > 0$, for $r=2,3,\ldots$ I want to compute

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\cdots(k-r+1) \frac{ \alpha^k e^{- \alpha}}{k!} $$

The book says that this infinite sum has a closed form solution: $\alpha^r$

#### Attempt:

Since $k! = (k-r+2)! \cdot k(k-1)\cdots(k-r+1) $ and since $e^{- \alpha }$ does not depend on $k$, we have

$$ e^{- \alpha} \sum_{k \geq 0 } \frac{k!}{(k-r+2)!} \frac{ \alpha^k}{k!}  $$

But this is stil hard to manage. How Can I handle this problem > is there any tick?

Comment: Do you regard this a closed form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^k}{k!} = e^\alpha.
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $\alpha$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k \frac{\alpha^{k-1}}{k!} = e^\alpha.
$$
Take the derivative again:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1) \frac{\alpha^{k-2}}{k!} = e^\alpha.
$$
And so on. After $r$ repetitions, you get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\cdots(k-r+1) \frac{\alpha^{k-r}}{k!} = e^\alpha.
$$
This directly implies your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get a closed form. Applying the operator $(xD)^r$ to the identity

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^k}{k!} = e^{\alpha} $$

gives

$$S =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\cdots(k-r+1) \frac{ \alpha^k }{k!} = (xD)^r e^{\alpha}= \sum_{k=0}^{r} {r\brace k}\alpha^k D^ke^{\alpha} $$

$$ \implies S = e^{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{r} {r \brace k}\alpha^k $$

> $$ \implies e^{-\alpha} S = \sum_{k=0}^{r} {r\brace k}\alpha^k, $$

where ${r\choose k}$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind.

**Note:**

> $$ (xD)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\brace k}\alpha^k D^k .$$